# Is my proof valid for the formula of elevation in boiling point?

Tags: thermodynamics, boiling-point, vapor-pressure, colligative-properties

Is my proof valid for the formula of elevation in boiling point?

`proof`

By Clausius clayperon equation,
$$\ln(P)=-\frac{∆H_v}{RT}+c$$
Differentiating,
$$\frac{dP}{P}=\frac{∆H_v dT}{RT^2}$$
Approximating $dP\approx ∆P$ , $dT\approx ∆T$,
$$\frac{∆P}{P}=\frac{∆H_v∆T}{RT^2}$$
Let $∆P=P_{solution}-∆P_{solvent}$ and $T^2\approx T_{boiling}^2$ also $∆T=$ Change in boiling point,

By the formula for relative lowering of vapour pressure,
$\frac{∆P}{P}=mf_{solute}$
$$mf_{solute}=\frac{∆H_v∆T_{boiling}}{RT_{boiling,solvent}^2}$$
$$∆T=\Big(\frac{RT_b^2}{∆H_v}\Big)mf_{solute}$$
But i don't know how to proceed further, can anyone help?

The actual formula differs from mine as,
$$∆T=\Big(\frac{RT_b^2}{∆H_v}\Big)molality_{solute}$$

Comment: I'm not sure that you *can* go further; is there a reason you expect to be able to do so?

Comment: I updated the question @a-cyclohexane-molecule